# HTML5 hard error

Tags: html, joomla3.0

I have recently been doing some HTML on my server which is using latest joomla. When i wanted to play a video with this code:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" src="HTML5Sample.mov" controls></video>
```

It just says that Recording video or MIME type is not supported. I cant get through this problem. I tried every solution on stackoverflow but it keeps saying this. I would be happy of any kind of help.

Comment: What browser and version please?...

Comment: Latest firefoc version, and chrome. They are both latest versions. I kind a fixed it. I installed a addon Allvideos and i just vrote {mp4}Video{/mp4}, and is working.